# localtime() gets it wrong, says date = September 31

Tags: c, datetime, mktime, localtime

I am making a calendar program. The 'expand repeating events' code is giving me no end of trouble. I am expanding events by using mktime() to get a 'pure' time value, then adding the repeat delta (in this case, 604800 seconds or 7 days) to it. localtime() is then used to get a calendar struct back out.

This happens:

Original event: September 10

```
{tm_sec = 0, tm_min = 0, tm_hour = 16, tm_mday = 10, tm_mon = 9,
 tm_year = 2012, tm_wday = 4, tm_yday = 283, tm_isdst = 0, 
 tm_gmtoff = -25200, tm_zone = 0x608ff0 "PDT"}
```

First repetition: September 17

```
{tm_sec = 0, tm_min = 0, tm_hour = 17, tm_mday = 17, tm_mon = 9,
 tm_year = 2012, tm_wday = 4, tm_yday = 290, tm_isdst = 1, 
 tm_gmtoff = -25200, tm_zone = 0x608ff0 "PDT"}
```

Second repetition: September 24

```
{tm_sec = 0, tm_min = 0, tm_hour = 16, tm_mday = 24, tm_mon = 9,
 tm_year = 2012, tm_wday = 4, tm_yday = 297, tm_isdst = 0,
 tm_gmtoff = -25200, tm_zone = 0x608ff0 "PDT"}
```

Third repetition: September 31?!

```
{tm_sec = 0, tm_min = 0, tm_hour = 16, tm_mday = 31, tm_mon = 9,
 tm_year = 2012, tm_wday = 4, tm_yday = 304, tm_isdst = 0,
 tm_gmtoff = -25200, tm_zone = 0x608ff0 "PDT"}
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? Will I have to fill in for `localtime()` myself?

Comment: Remember that `tm_year` is the number of years since 1900. So if you want year 2012 (this year) it should be 112.

Comment: "...It is **not** a compiler error..." (NB: I did not downvote this time - it's a mistake easy to make, I'm sure I'd have done this too...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html): the members of the `struct tm` structure are 0-based (as usually in C).

```
int    tm_mon   month of year [0,11]
```

So actually the month numbered `9` is the 10th month, which is October, and it has 31 days.

Comment: Even in the year 3912, which is what `tm_year == 2012` represents. BTW, month numbers are zero-based so they can be used as indices into an array of month names; `tm_mday` is one-based because it's not used as in index (we don't have names for days of the month, "Ides" notwithstanding).

Answer (score 2):

As H2CO3 pointed out, `tm_mon` is 0-based, so the date was actually October 31st, which makes sense.

I wanted to mention that simply adding 604800 seconds to advance 7 days is probably not what a user would want from a calendar program. 604800 is *exactly* seven days, but if the user wants a recurring event at 10:00 AM every seven days, adding 604800 seconds will not always result in a time at 10:00 AM because this ignores special considerations like Daylight Saving Time and leap seconds.

What you can do instead is add 7 to `tm_mday`. Don't worry about exceeding the number of days in the month because `mktime()` will correct it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't know mktime() would do that normalization.